# Given an array that is all words in the dictionary, assign a value to each word based on a numerical value assigned to each character in the alphabet

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have taken a list of words in the dictionary and turned them into a massive array.  I in turn created a script that ran through every word and broke down which alphabetical characters turned up the most.  So I have a list of values I have assigned to each character, with 26 being the value assigned to the most common letter, s, and 1 to the least common, q.

I in turn made a script that ran through all the words and assigned these values then can output them on the console like "fudge: 72"

```
            foreach (string word in masterList)
        {
            int wordValue = 0;
            foreach (char letter in word)
            {
                if (letter == 'a')
                {
                    wordValue += 23;
                }
                if (letter == 'b')
                {
                    wordValue += 10;
                }
                if (letter == 'c')
                {
                    wordValue += 14;
                }
                if (letter == 'd')
                {
                    wordValue += 16;
                }
                if (letter == 'e')
                {
                    wordValue += 25;
                }
                if (letter == 'f')
                {
                    wordValue += 7;
                }
                if (letter == 'g')
                {
                    wordValue += 9;
                }
                if (letter == 'h')
                {
                    wordValue += 24;
                }
                if (letter == 'i')
                {
                    wordValue += 20;
                }
                if (letter == 'j')
                {
                    wordValue += 2;
                }
                if (letter == 'k')
                {
                    wordValue += 8;
                }
                if (letter == 'l')
                {
                    wordValue += 18;
                }
                if (letter == 'm')
                {
                    wordValue += 11;
                }
                if (letter == 'n')
                {
                    wordValue += 17;
                }
                if (letter == 'o')
                {
                    wordValue += 21;
                }
                if (letter == 'p')
                {
                    wordValue += 13;
                }
                if (letter == 'q')
                {
                    wordValue += 1;
                }
                if (letter == 'r')
                {
                    wordValue += 22;
                }
                if (letter == 's')
                {
                    wordValue += 26;
                }
                if (letter == 't')
                {
                    wordValue += 19;
                }
                if (letter == 'u')
                {
                    wordValue += 15;
                }
                if (letter == 'v')
                {
                    wordValue += 5;
                }
                if (letter == 'w')
                {
                    wordValue += 6;
                }
                if (letter == 'x')
                {
                    wordValue += 4;
                }
                if (letter == 'y')
                {
                    wordValue += 12;
                }
                if (letter == 'z')
                {
                    wordValue += 3;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(word + ": " + wordValue);
        }
```

However, I would like to assign the "wordValue" to each "word" and then sort the array by highest value "wordValue" to least.

Comment: Add each word to a List<Word>, where Word is your internal class with 2 members `string word` and `int wordValue`. Then you can use LINQ to print the list by descending order of wordValue.

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to do. If you have a list of words and … _” I in turn created a script that ran through every word and broke down which alphabetical characters turned up the most. So I have a list of values I have assigned to each character, with 26 being the value assigned to the most common letter, s, and 1 to the least common, q.”_ … ? …

Comment: It looks like you have HARD CODED and posted this relationship .. i.e…, “a = 23”, “b=10” etc… HOWEVER, if you had a “different” list of words, then wouldn’t the values of each letter be “different” than what your current code shows? Are you planning on re-writing your code with EACH new list of words? It looks to me that you need a method that “creates” this relationship based on the given list of words as it would “change” with each “different” list of words?

Comment: There are other questions like… what “scale” would you use if NOT ALL characters in the alphabet exist in the list of words? I suggest a method that takes the list of words and returns a `Dictionary<char, int>` where each `char` would be `a-z?` and `int` would be the number of times each char is used in the list of the given words. After you have “created” this `Dictionary<char, int>` then you could loop through each word in the list and assign it a value using the dictionary. Point being the `Dictionary<char, int>` would be different and unique to any given list of words.

Comment: What if two or more letters have been used the SAME number of times? How would you determine “what” values to give each of those characters that have the same number of usages? This is beginning to smell fishy and you need to clarify how you want to deal with ambiguity that is bound to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can compact your scoring a bit. Every letter gets a score of its position in a string with q at the leftmost and s at the rightmost:

```
class WordCalc{

    private string _scores = "qjzxvwfkgbmypcudnltiorahes";

    public int WordScore(string word) => word.Sum(c => _scores.IndexOf(c)+1);
```

So you can use it to order a list of words:

```
var calc = new WordCalc();
words.OrderByDescending(w => calc.WordScore(w));
```

---

If you want to speed the lookup up some if, say, you have lots of words to do:

```
class WordCalc{

    private Dictionary<char, int> _scores;
    

    public WordCalc(string scoreLetters = "qjzxvwfkgbmypcudnltiorahes"){
      _scores = scoreLetters
        .Select((c,i) => new { C= c, S = i+1})
        .ToDictionary(at => at.C, at => at.S);
    }

    public int WordScore(string word) => word.Sum(c => _scores.TryGetValue(c, out var s) ? s : 0);
```

We make a dictionary that maps chars to scores, and use that. IndexOf returns -1 when it doesn't find a char which we +1 to, so unknown chars score 0. Dictionary would crash if looked up an unknown char so instead we try and get the value, and if it succeeds we use it, otherwise we use 0

There's another trick that relies on c# being able to treat chars and ints as equivalent

```
class WordCalc
{

    private int[] _scores = new int[65535];


    public WordCalc(string scoreLetters = "qjzxvwfkgbmypcudnltiorahes")
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < scoreLetters.Length; x++)
            _scores[scoreLetters[x]] = x+1;
        
    }

    public int WordScore(string word) => word.Sum(c => _scores[c]);
}
```

We declare an int array big enough to hold every char; mostly they're zeroes, but then we run a loop that pulls the char at index `x` and uses it to index the array. Because `q` as a char has a value of 113, array index 113 in `_scores` gets set to `x+1` i.e. 1. This continues so that our "mostly zero" mapping array has some non zero values in, which are the scores for those letters. `j` is 106, so index `scores[106]` is `2` and so on

When we come to score a word, we can quickly take a char from it - e.g. `h` in "hello", C# implicitly converts `h` to `104`, goes to `_scores[104]`, finds `24` (because `h` was at the 23rd position in scoreLetters) and that is the score for that letter. This lookup is even faster than a dictionary..